# Query a ManyToMany relation and display the good result in Symfony with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, dql

in order to know how it really works, there is an [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150527/symfony-doctrine-sql-to-dql-error-invalid-pathexpression-statefieldpathexpre/28167575?noredirect=1#comment44716873_28167575) question from Stack website, and notice that I have the similar problem.

In my *SQl database*, I have two tables: **Adverts** and **Categories**

Indeed, the `Adverts` table can contain **MANY** `Categories`, and of course a `Category` can be in many `Adverts`.

So I have a ***ManyToMany*** relation between the two tables. in SQL, Doctrine creates me a pivot table named adverts_categories. So far there are no problems , everything is theoretically correct.

So, in my SQl database, I have three tables: `adverts`, `adverts_categories` and `categories` like this:

```
    adverts
+-------------+--------------+
| id          | int(11)      |
| ...         | ...          |
+-------------+--------------+

    adverts_categories 
+---------------+--------------+
| adverts_id    | int(11)      |
| categories_id | int(11)      |
+---------------+--------------+

    categories
+-------------+-------------+
| id          | int(11)     |
| ...         | ...         |
+-------------+-------------+
```

And in my Symfony project, in my entity folder I have just the two entities name `Adverts.php` and `Categories.php`, which is theoretically correct for now too.

Here's the code for `Adverts.php`:

```
class Adverts
{
     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

 /**
 * @var \Users
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="users_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $users;

     /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categories", inversedBy="adverts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="adverts_categories",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adverts_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categories_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $categories;
```

And here's the code for `Categories.php`:
class Categories

```
{
     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Adverts", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $adverts;
```

So now, when I try to make a query in order to have the results of this request an error occured.
Here's the code in my controller:

```
public function indexAdvertsAction() {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $advert= $em->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:Adverts');

$queryAdverts = $em->createQuery('SELECT a
                                    FROM MySpaceMyBundle:Adverts a, MySpaceMyBundle:Users u, MySpaceMyBundle:Categories c
                                    WHERE a.categories = c.id
                                    AND a.users = a.id ');

$advert= $queryAdverts->getResult();

        return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:indexAdverts.html.twig', array('advert' => $advert ));
    }
```

The error is:

> [Semantical Error] line ..., col ... near 'categories': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
>   SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

I really don't understand. Someone could help?

---

UPADTE

if it could help for searching an answer, I would like to display all the result in a  in my twig `indexAdverts.html.twig`, here's the code:

```
{% for adverts in advert%}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ adverts.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ adverts.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ adverts.users }}</td>
       <td>{{ adverts.categories }}</td>
       <td><a href="{{ path('editAdverts', {'name': adverts.name}) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button></a></td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Probably  WHERE a.categories = c.id should be a.categories = c. Take a look at the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226545/invalid-pathexpression-statefieldpathexpression-or-singlevaluedassociationfield

Comment: Your suggestion does not match. Moreover, the fact is that I have a ManyToMany relation. That's why it gives me the same error.

Comment: DQL is a bit different than SQL especially with joins.  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins.  I would also suggest dropping users and your where conditions just until you see how dql works.

Comment: @Cerad, I also tried the JOIN like this: `$queryAdverts = $em->createQuery('SELECT a
                                    FROM MySpaceMyBundle:Adverts a, MySpaceMyBundle:Users u JOIN MySpaceMyBundle:Categories c
                                    WHERE a.categories = c.id
                                    AND a.users = a.id ');`
And I have exactly the same error

Comment: Why are you using a repo when you could use a getter on the entity directly?

Comment: @Jean, look at my Update in my question. If I use a **dql/query** in my _controller_ is because I need to put all displaying result in a `<table>` in my twig. What do you suggest exactly?

Comment: Consider trying the join using the syntax as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use DQL or others direct queries in your controllers if not really necessary. You should do this:

```
public function indexAdvertsAction() {
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $adverts = $em->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:Adverts')->findAll();

    return $this->render(
         'MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:indexAdverts.html.twig',
         array('adverts' => $adverts )
    );
}
```

Then, in your template, the advert entity will take care of the rest, thanks to the correct relations mapping:

```
{% for adverts in advert%}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ adverts.id }}</td>
       <td>{{ adverts.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ adverts.users }}</td>
       <td>
           {% for category in adverts.categories %}
               {{ adverts.categories }}
           {% endfor %}
       </td>
       <td>
           <a href="{{ path('editAdverts', {'name': adverts.name}) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button></a>
       </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I already try, and in fact I have **this error** when I do that: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string in My\Path\Of\My\Project\app\cache\dev\twig\bf\66\146a31a62bf6f2a549d2604fb5be9c4530ab760a10169af08e8a5b72e9ee.php line ...") in MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:indexAdverts.html.twig at line ...`. **The line causing this error is where I insert in my <table>:** `<td>{{ adverts.categories }}</td>`.

Comment: That's because you're trying to print the full relation instead of cycling it over. I'll edit the answer including a template example

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE a.categories = c.id
```

This line should cause the error. I think in your case, you should use `a.categories.id` instead of `a.categories`.
You can't equalize an object with an integer.

Comment: I try to of course, but if I make like you suggest I have this error: `[Syntax Error] line ..., col ...: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '.'`

Comment: Nope.  DQL is not SQL.